# Frequently receiving "Could not get a reference to rendering Engine"

Tags: evopdf

While sending the html string to 
"var document = _converter.GetPdfDocumentObjectFromHtmlString(html);"
 I receive the below exception
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lmsX.png)

Any idea of what may cause the issue? I have not seen this question anywhere in evopdf support does anyone of you get the same?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the rendering was unexpectedly closed by an external program. Do you have any anti-virus software installed or other something that could stop the execution of other programs? You can temporary deactivate such a software to determine if this can be a posible cause for this problem.